# Raspberry Pi (or an alternative) with HDMI auto-switch

Tags: hdmi

I want to use Raspberry Pi 3 with an HDMI auto-switch, but I understand that the Raspberry Pi is an "always-on" computer, so auto-sensing doesn't work with it (the HDMI port keeps appearing active even if I shut the RPi down)

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

What if I powered the Raspberry Pi from a powered USB hub instead of directly from the wall, would that make a difference?

If it's impossible with Raspberry Pi, than is it possible with an alternative such as Orange Pi or Odroid C2?